# FileUpload does not contain the file when popup open

Tags: c#, asp.net

after upload the file  then upload button click it shows the msg if already file exits do you want overwrite it? here i used the popup and cancel control id but i want use ok button and then press the ok button load the file and overrite the old one how to write the code in asp.net using c#

Comment: _What have you tried?_ *™*

Comment: i wanna use modal popup control in that popup i want click a button then saved(Overrite) coding

Answer (score 0):

For check exists file you can use this code

```
var folderfile4 = Server.MapPath("~/files/Path");
string saveflFile4 = folderfile4 + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(flFile4);
if(!File.Exists(saveflFile4))
    txtFile4.SaveAs(saveflFile4);
else
    txtError.Text = "File exists";
```

Comment: i wanna  use modal popup control in that popup i want click a button then saved(Overrite) coding